# Can I get free accommodation when traveling on Jet Airways with a long layover?

Tags: air-travel, india, layovers, jet-airways, gau

I am Travelling from Muscat to Dibrugarh with two layovers in between:

Muscat → New Delhi
Delhi → Guwahati
Guwahati → Dibrugarh

But at Guwahati it's a 21 hour long layover.
Is Jet Airways going to help me with this or not? Will they provide accommodation or I have to wait at the airport only?

Answer (score 7):

No, the airline won't provide accommodation. [Jet Airways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_Airways) is a semi-lowcost airline and doesn't have any special programs for people on a long layover. Your only options are to wait at the airport or get a hotel room close to the airport.

Comment: Book yourself a hotel room, 21 hours in Guwahati Airport would be pure torture (assuming it is even open 24 hours a day).